# Adding a form seemed to cause a 'lockout' of my other forms

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

Working on a fairly simple database application in visual studio 2017 and c# with a login screen to unlock all the other forms. Working just fine.

Tried adding another form for another feature and suddenly this caused the login screen to be 'locked out', as in it appears on startup like it should but nothing is selectable, everything is greyed out.

I have tried removing every single reference I can find to the newly created form but still my entire program is basically broken from just adding a form. I had added forms before this with no problems.

I'm not expecting anyone to wave a magic wand and fix it but if anyone has any pointers of what to check or look for? Happy to answer questions and go into more specifics if needed.

Comment: Sounds as if the new form is modal but is not visible (outside the screen, perhaps?). Can you close it hitting enter or one of the shortcuts for standard buttons? Through ESC or Ctrl-F4? You could create a minimal test version of the form which just has an OK button on it so that you can be sure to trigger that with Enter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I discovered that the main parent form had for some reason had its enabled property set to false. I have absolutely no idea why this would have happened.